# Api Gateway Architecture handling REST endpoint permission validation

Tags: c#, rest, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi, api-gateway

I am designing how we handle authorization and authentication for our micro-services, one idea is to move endpoint validation e.g., `[Authorize(Roles = "que.users.read")]` to the API gateway instead. This means our service APIs will not have any authentication, the endpoints will just look like this; e.g., `[Authorize, AllowAnonymous]`.

This means in the permissions table we add another column mapping the endpoint e.g.,
[image]

Each permission is linked to a role and each role is linked to a user etcetera etcetera. This way, there's no need to add any security considering the services' APIs will be behind a firewall and inaccessible to the public?

Is this a good design in terms of security considering the services' APIs are not exposed to the public? only the gateway is.

Also from the sketch below notice, we plan to inject tenant_id to HTTP headers as opposed to injecting it as part of the token claims. not sure which is best here, claims or HTTP headers.

[image]